# Angular slick grid error after deployed package

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid, slickgriduniversal

I am using Angular slickgid. Recently i have upgraded to slickgrid 7.0.3.  (https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid)
After i upgraded its working fine using **ng s**, **The grid loading perfectly.**
When i generate using ng build (no error and generate package success fully ) and locally i have run the generated file using   **http-server dist\browser**  i am getting below error when page loads. (Ng build)

```
chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:38  ERROR TypeError: Function.prototype.toString requires that 'this' be a Function
    at Boolean.toString (<anonymous>)
    at Boolean.l (polyfills-ACABCK6S.js:2:3565)
    at i.isPlainObject (chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:46:12916)
    at i.extend (chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:46:13381)
    at i.mergeGridOptions (chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:67:37685)
    at i.initialization (chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:67:20979)
    at i.ngAfterViewInit (chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:67:18331)
    at XA (chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:38:13512)
    at a4 (chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:38:13662)
    at yM (chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:38:13418)
handleError @ chunk-JQKIRE7U.js:38
```

I am struggling issue since 3 days. Please some one help me to debug the same.

EDIT:After ngOnInit() i am getting this error in the console.

NOTE : I am having issue only in deployed packaged ( ng s loading the grid perfectly

[image]

```
   <angular-slickgrid gridId="userGrid" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                                [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [dataset]="dataset"
                                (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event.detail)">
                            </angular-slickgrid>
```

TS Code:

```
constructor() {this.graphqlService = new GraphqlService();}
ngOnInit(): void {this.columnDefinitions = [
      {
        id: 'edit',
        field: 'id',
        excludeFromColumnPicker: true,
        excludeFromExport: true,
        excludeFromGridMenu: true,
        excludeFromHeaderMenu: true,
        formatter: Formatters.icon , params: { iconCssClass: 'fa fa-pencil pointer' },
        minWidth: 30,
        maxWidth: 30,
        onCellClick: (e: Event, args: OnEventArgs) => { this.router.navigate(['/user/user-detail/' + args.dataContext.id]);}
      },
     
      { id: 'userName', field: 'userName', name: 'User Id', filterable: true, sortable: true },
      { id: 'fullName', field: 'fullName', name: 'Name', filterable: true, sortable: true }
      ];

    this.gridOptions = {
       excelExportOptions:{
         sanitizeDataExport: true,          
          exportWithFormatter:true,
        },

      backendServiceApi: {
        service: this.graphqlService,
        
        options: {
          columnDefinitions: this.columnDefinitions,
          datasetName: GRAPHQL_QUERY_DATASET_NAME,
          
        },
       
        process: (query):any => this.getUsers(),      

      }
    };
    
  }

getUsers(): Observable<GraphqlPaginatedResult> {
  

    var args = this.pageService.getPageArgs(this.angularGrid);
    
    return this.dataService.searchUsers(args)
      .pipe(map(
        (page:any) => {
          var result: GraphqlPaginatedResult = {                    
            data: {
              [GRAPHQL_QUERY_DATASET_NAME]: {
                nodes: page.items,
               
                totalCount: page.totalCount,
              }
            }
          };
          
          return result;
        }));
  }
 angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
  
    this.angularGrid = angularGrid;
  
  }
```

ng build --verbose getting below

```
 Building...
One or more browsers which are configured in the project's Browserslist configuration will be ignored as ES5 output is not supported by the Angular CLI.
⠙ Building...
● [DEBUG] Failed to read directory "D:\\Personal\\Workspace\\CorePigmyWeb\\angular:script\\global:scripts": open D:\Personal\Workspace\CorePigmyWeb\angular:script: The system cannot find the file specified.


  scripts-NCWJS6GS.js  58.7kb

Done in 28ms

34.0kb

⠸ Building...
[DEBUG] Indirect calls to "require" will not be bundled [indirect-require]

    node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js:22:39:
      22 │           var t = "function" == typeof require && require;
         ╵                                        ~~~~~~~

● [DEBUG] Indirect calls to "require" will not be bundled [indirect-require]

    node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js:22:50:
      22 │           var t = "function" == typeof require && require;
         ╵                                                   ~~~~~~~

● [DEBUG] Indirect calls to "require" will not be bundled [indirect-require]

    node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js:38:38:
      38 │     for (var l = "function" == typeof require && require, e = 0; e < h.length; e++) u(h[e]);
         ╵                                       ~~~~~~~

● [DEBUG] Indirect calls to "require" will not be bundled [indirect-require]

    node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js:38:49:
      38 │     for (var l = "function" == typeof require && require, e = 0; e < h.length; e++) u(h[e]);
         ╵                                                  ~~~~~~~
⠧ Building...
● [DEBUG] Top-level "this" will be replaced with undefined since this file is an ECMAScript module [this-is-undefined-in-esm]

    node_modules/@slickgrid-universal/common/dist/esm/formatters/multipleFormatter.js:21:34:
      21 │     currentValue = formatter.call(this, row, cell, currentValue, columnDef, dataContext, grid);
         │                                   ~~~~
         ╵                                   undefined

  This file is considered to be an ECMAScript module because of the "export" keyword here:

    node_modules/@slickgrid-universal/common/dist/esm/formatters/multipleFormatter.js:7:0:
      7 │ export const multipleFormatter = (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext, grid) => {
        ╵ ~~~~~~
⠇ Building...

  chunk-JQKIRE7U.js    1.6mb
  main-VVD2PVG7.js   463.0kb
  chunk-DEKKHDHY.js   65.3kb
  chunk-WCYH7E3Y.js   38.1kb
  chunk-NONLWZGG.js   37.2kb
  chunk-FWIQXCOO.js   35.9kb
  chunk-RWBMCJU6.js   25.4kb
  chunk-6NBPDX4E.js   20.5kb
  chunk-7A6ZKOF6.js   17.8kb
  chunk-7AXFXNEN.js   10.8kb
  chunk-7EFFINHE.js    4.5kb
  chunk-SBSTWZEV.js    2.4kb
  chunk-NAIX5QOX.js    1.8kb
  chunk-WWHRMCBO.js    1.6kb
  chunk-SPBBN3FK.js    1.3kb
  ...and 5 more output files...

⠏ Building...
▲ [WARNING] `alert-variant()` has been deprecated as of v4.3.0. It will be removed entirely in v6.0.0. [plugin angular-sass]

    angular:styles/global:styles:7:8:
      7 │ @import 'src/scss/style.scss';
        ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


▲ [WARNING] `list-group-item-variant()` has been deprecated as of v4.3.0. It will be removed entirely in v6.0.0. [plugin angular-sass]

    angular:styles/global:styles:7:8:
      7 │ @import 'src/scss/style.scss';
        ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

⠋ Building...
▲ [WARNING] 4 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  .form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.
  .form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.
  .form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.
  .form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.

                                                                                                                                                    
Initial Chunk Files   | Names              |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
chunk-JQKIRE7U.js     | -                  |   1.56 MB |               361.05 kB
styles-AT4IW3U3.css   | styles             | 822.61 kB |                70.50 kB
main-VVD2PVG7.js      | main               | 462.96 kB |                87.61 kB
scripts-NCWJS6GS.js   | scripts            |  58.74 kB |                14.57 kB
polyfills-ACABCK6S.js | polyfills          |  33.96 kB |                11.03 kB
chunk-7EFFINHE.js     | -                  |   4.55 kB |               962 bytes
chunk-SBSTWZEV.js     | -                  |   2.41 kB |               787 bytes
chunk-NAIX5QOX.js     | -                  |   1.82 kB |               557 bytes
chunk-SPBBN3FK.js     | -                  |   1.34 kB |               453 bytes
chunk-MUIJUO33.js     | -                  |   1.34 kB |               466 bytes
chunk-IMFXHPGH.js     | -                  |   1.32 kB |               476 bytes
chunk-AI5VQ6CL.js     | -                  |   1.17 kB |               387 bytes
chunk-TNZ3CRMV.js     | -                  |   1.07 kB |               389 bytes
chunk-2NDHNDTE.js     | -                  | 788 bytes |               788 bytes

                      | Initial Total      |   2.92 MB |               549.89 kB

Lazy Chunk Files      | Names              |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
chunk-DEKKHDHY.js     | collection-module  |  65.31 kB |                10.83 kB
chunk-WCYH7E3Y.js     | user-module        |  38.09 kB |                 7.17 kB
chunk-NONLWZGG.js     | account-module     |  37.21 kB |                 6.73 kB
chunk-FWIQXCOO.js     | branch-module      |  35.93 kB |                 7.11 kB
chunk-RWBMCJU6.js     | bank-module        |  25.44 kB |                 4.94 kB
chunk-6NBPDX4E.js     | reports-module     |  20.47 kB |                 3.34 kB
chunk-7A6ZKOF6.js     | transaction-module |  17.77 kB |                 4.37 kB
chunk-7AXFXNEN.js     | -                  |  10.79 kB |                 3.45 kB
chunk-WWHRMCBO.js     | -                  |   1.57 kB |               300 bytes

Application bundle generation complete.
```

Comment: Can you please share some ts file code regarding slider.

Comment: I have updated code at least  some  one help me debug the same

Comment: The first issue seems to be related to another open issue, https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/issues/1334, but for the second issue with jszip, you need to make sure that you provide its path to your `tsconfig.json` file, it's mentioned in the Quick Start https://ghiscoding.gitbook.io/angular-slickgrid/getting-started/quick-start

Comment: Thanks I checked with latest version. Now I think fixed.. but  Jszip I already added before.. still that all  message showing jszip and common.. I will check download excel later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Angular-Slickgrid v7.1.0 should resolve this issue. The problem was fixed by reimplementing the `extend` with the `node-extend` approach.

For jszip, you should follow all instructions from the new documentation website, take a look at the [Quick Start](https://ghiscoding.gitbook.io/angular-slickgrid/getting-started/quick-start)

EDIT

`excel-builder-webpacker` was rewritten to a new [excel-builder-vanilla](https://github.com/ghiscoding/excel-builder-vanilla) fork, it no longer requires JSZip (it now uses `fflate`) and you no longer need to care about it either since `fflate` doesn't require any particular config from your side. The reason for the new fork was mainly to modernize the project, with these changes

- drop `Q` (replaced by native `Promise`)
- drop `Lodash` (replaced by native JS code)
- replace `JSZip` with `fflate` (the latter supports ESM and Tree Shaking)

This new librare is now used in Angular-Slickgrid v7.4.x and higher

Comment: Thanks for now issue resolved..Excel file also downloaded.. I have already added  "paths": {
      "jszip": ["../node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"]
    }    but console messaage is getting as before  i just informing ...but issue resolved only mesage displaying in cosole.